# Why exactly does numpy.sum() gives different results on the same matrix with different order, where sum() does not?

Tags: python, numpy, sum

When I initialize two random matrices (here of shape (6,2)), and re-order the rows, np.sum() will give me different results. I understand this is likely due to numerical errors, as the differences are small, but how exactly is np.sum() summing the elements? How can I replicate the results for each matrix order?

```
x1 = np.array([[-0.31381854, -0.05944943],
               [ 0.3848904 , -0.36534384],
               [ 1.1122322 ,  1.2480698 ],
               [-1.4493011 ,  0.5094067 ],
               [ 0.00905334,  0.77591574],
               [ 0.25694364, -2.108599  ]], dtype=np.float32)

x2 = np.array([[-0.31381854, -0.05944943],
               [ 1.1122322 ,  1.2480698 ],
               [ 0.00905334,  0.77591574],
               [ 0.3848904 , -0.36534384],
               [-1.4493011 ,  0.5094067 ],
               [ 0.25694364, -2.108599  ]], dtype=np.float32)
    

print(np.sum(x1))
print(np.sum(x2))
0.0
-2.3841858e-07
```

Although they have the exact same elements per column and row, the sums are different.

If I sum all elements using the sum() function, the results do not disagree:

```
print(sum(sum(x1)))
print(sum(sum(x2)))
-5.960464477539063e-08
-5.960464477539063e-08
```

When I sum the columns invidividually, using the python sum() function, I get the same resulting sum:

```
print(sum(x1[:,0]))
print(sum(x2[:,0]))
-6.705522537231445e-08
-6.705522537231445e-08

print(sum(x1[:,1]))
print(sum(x2[:,1]))
-2.9802322387695312e-08
-2.9802322387695312e-08
```

But again, if I sum the columns separately, this time using np.sum(  axis=1),  the results are different:

```
print(np.sum(x1),1)
print(np.sum(x2),1)
-2.3841858e-07 1
0.0 1
```

This is an issue for large matrices with thousands of elements, where the numerical inaccuracies sum up to be massive differences.

I just don't understand how np.sum() is operating, in a way that a simple sum is giving such different results, where the python canonical sum() function does not!

Comment: I don't think `x1[[0, 2, 4, 1, 3, 5]] == x2` is true. When I do `x1.sum()` with the copy-pasted array, I get 0.0 as you do. When I do `x1[[0, 2, 4, 1, 3, 5]].sum()`, I get 0.0 as well. That implies `x2 != x1[[0, 2, 4, 1, 3, 5]]`

Comment: Nevermind. This is a good question. I see what is happening now

Comment: My guess is that Sum adds things sequentially in the order they appear. `np.sum` divides the things into chunks for vectorization and addition is not really associative due to floating point errors.

Comment: @QuangHoang. It's simpler: one is using double, one is float

Comment: @MadPhysicist so np.sum automatically converts float32 data to float64? That’s not good.

Comment: @QuangHoang. It doesn't. Python doesn't have a float32 type, so the second sum does. `sum(x1).dtype -> float32`, `sum(sum(x1)).dtype -> float64`

Comment: Side note to @hirchme, `print(sum(x1), 1)` is not summing along axis=1.

Comment: @QuangHoang. What's really weird is that I was able to reproduce the result OP shows, but no longer can.

Comment: The python `sum` delegates the action the argument's `add` method.  If you want a pure Python sum, use `sum(x1.ravel().tolist())`.

Comment: @OP. I am no longer able to reproduce your result...

Comment: @MadPhysicist I think you pointed out an important cause here, as when I cast the original arrays to float64, then both sum() and np.sum() agree on the results.

Comment: Regardless, I think my point on floating point precision is still valid. The problem will be more prominent as the data size grows bigger (and `float32` only helps magnifying it even more).

Comment: Without reading the source code, the algorithm is mentioned a little in the [documentation](https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/generated/numpy.sum.html): "However, often numpy will use a numerically better approach (partial pairwise summation) leading to improved precision in many use-cases."

Comment: Maybe the version of numpy being used here should also be specified? Unable to reproduce the issue as well.